# Google Sheets filter command with search function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a search function across multiple sheets and using the filter command has been the best method so far but wanted to know if you could display all information across the sheets for one individual.

The current filter code that displays all information from the 2 sheets:

```
={filter(Sheet1!A2:C10, len(Sheet1!A2:A10)); filter(Sheet2!A2:C3, len(Sheet2!A2:A3))}
```

I am using cell B2 as the search box. A name will be entered into cell B2 that the user wants to search for. Can cell B2 be added into the code above so it displays all information only about the one name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with query

```
=query({Sheet1!A2:C;Sheet2!A2:C},"select * where Col1 = '"&B2&"' ")
```